# Collapse Rows in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have my input as below:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | txt1  | txt2   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | null  | aaaaaa |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | bbbbb | null   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | cccc  | null   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | dddd  | null   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | null  | eeeee  |
+----+-------+--------+
```

and expecting the output as:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | txt1  | txt2   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | bbbbb | aaaaaa |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | cccc  | eeeee  |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | dddd  | null   |
+----+-------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this in Hive? I have tried below query but it behaves like a cross join.

```
select distinct id, myq,myq1 from (
select id, 
collect_set(txt1)  as txt1_set, 
collect_set(txt2)  as txt2_set
from add_flat group by addr_who)
lateral view explode(txt1_set) q as myq
lateral view explode(txt2_set) q1 as myq1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather tricky.  You want to "stack" the columns.  One method unpivots the values, filters, and re-aggregates:

```
select id, 
       max(case when which = 1 then txt end) as txt1,
       max(case when which = 2 then txt end) as txt2
from (select tt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by which order by txt) as seqnum
      from ((select id, txt1 as txt, 1 as which
             from t
            ) union all
            (select id, txt2 as txt, 2 as which
             from t
            )
           ) tt
      where txt is not null
     ) tt
group by id, seqnum
order by id, seqnum;
```

Note that the results within each column are order based on the `order by` in `row_number()`.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically multi-sets), so this is the only way to control the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join` and `row_number` as follows:

```
Select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       t1.txt1, t2.txt2
From
(Select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by order by txt1) as rn
   From t where txt1 is not null) t1
Full join
(Select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by order by txt2) as rn
   From t where txt2 is not null) t2
On t1.id = t2.id and t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

You need posexplode and FULL JOIN on position:

```
with mytable as (
select stack (5,
1, null   , 'aaaaaa',
1, 'bbbbb', null   ,
1, 'cccc' , null   ,
1, 'dddd' , null   ,
1, null   , 'eeeee' 
) as ( id, txt1, txt2)
),

agg as (
select id, 
collect_set(txt1)  as txt1_set,
collect_set(txt2)  as txt2_set
from mytable group by id
) 

select coalesce(a.id, b.id) id, a.myq, b.myq1
from
(select id, myq,pos
       from agg
       lateral view outer posexplode(txt1_set) q as pos, myq
) a full join 
(select id, myq1, pos
       from agg
       lateral view outer posexplode(txt2_set) q as pos, myq1
) b ON a.id=b.id and a.pos=b.pos
```

Result:

```
id  a.myq   b.myq1
1   bbbbb   aaaaaa
1   cccc    eeeee
1   dddd    NULL
```